# SharePoint content database does not stop growing

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sql-server-2014

I created a secondary content database for my SharePoint site.

In SQL Server, I set the Maximum File Size to 100 MB for the first content database.

Then I started adding documents to the site and I expected SharePoint start using the second content db when the first one reaches to 100 MB.

But surprisingly, it kept using the first content db, regardless of site limit. And now the size of the first content db is beyond 100 MB.

Does anyone can explain, why it did not work as I expected?

Comment: You set the max file size for the mdf to 100mb and it grew past that? ( I assume there are no ndf's)

Comment: You set the file size to GROW by 100 MB? Or the maximum size value? Can you post the settings?

Comment: @scsimon, yes, there is only one mdf and it passes the limit. that's why I'm surprising

Comment: @JacobH, i have set the auto growth by 1 MB and have set the limit to 100 MB

Comment: Did you *change* files and not restart the SQL service? SQL will use the previous one until restart. Probably with the old settings (not sure there).

Comment: @JacobH, Thanks for comment. I changed the file limit and I did not restart the service. Are you sure it won't apply unless I restart?